# How to implement edit/delete behaviour on an embedded tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview

So I have an embedded tableview and I want to implement edit/delete behaviour: [image: Embedded tableview]

In my HomePageViewController I have:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
}
```

However, all that happens is when I click on the edit button, it says done, and the embedded tableview does nothing at all. When I put the above code in the tableview nothing happens.

How do I get the navigation controller/parent view controller to recognise the embedded table view?

Comment: To the person who downvoted this question - I would like some feedback please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're using an embed segue to embed a UITableViewController. In your parent view controller, you can do 1 of 2 things easily to achieve you goal.

#### Method 1: Use the child view controller's edit button

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Find and (optionally assign it to a variable for later convenience) the embedded controller, IBOutlets aren't available for VCs embedded within a storyboard
    let childControllers = childViewControllers.filter { return $0 is EventTableViewController }
    let embeddedController = childControllers[0] as! EventTableViewController

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = embeddedController.editButtonItem
}
```

#### Method 2: Forward edit events to child view controllers

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editButtonItem
}

override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    // Forward editing state to children
    childViewControllers.forEach { $0.setEditing(editing, animated: animated) }
}
```

**Note**: `editButtonItem` was exposed in iOS 10 (but [was implemented](https://github.com/ultramiraculous/iOS9-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIViewController.h#L859) much earlier). For deployment targets less than iOS 10, you can use a custom edit button combined with method 2.

Comment: I presume by 'childTabBarControllers' do you meant 'childControllers'. But this worked - thank you!

Comment: Yeah, that was an artifact of morphing my implementation to fit your situation. I fixed it.

Comment: Also method 1 worked perfectly fine, but thank you for including both methods

Comment: Yeah, method 1 is super clean and clear what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, you can't use the automatic behavior of the edit button. It's up to you to implement it yourself. You need to toggle both the `isEditing` of the table view and the appearance of the button.  Here's an example from one of my own apps:

```
func doEdit(_ sender: Any?) {
    var which : UIBarButtonSystemItem
    if !self.tableView.isEditing {
        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated:true)
        which = .done
    } else {
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated:true)
        which = .edit
    }
    let b = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: which, 
        target: self, action: #selector(doEdit))
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = b
}
```